TypeError: error sending request for url (https://api.cricapi.com/v1/currentMatches?apikey=myapiKey&offset=0)
I am exploring supabase edge functions and I tried to create and run one in my local machine, as part of the function I am trying to access some data related to cricket scores and I am trying to hit the URL https://api.cricapi.com/v1/currentMatches?apikey=myapikey&offset=0
But I am getting an error message
serving the request with /Supabase/supabase/functions/hello-world
[Error] TypeError: error sending request for url (https://api.cricapi.com/v1/currentMatches?apikey=myapikey&offset=0)
    at async mainFetch (ext:deno_fetch/26_fetch.js:170:12)
    at async fetch (ext:deno_fetch/26_fetch.js:391:7)
    at async Object.handler (file:///Supabase/supabase/functions/hello-world/index.ts:3:15)
    at async respond (ext:sb_core_main_js/js/http.js:163:14)

My code is as follows:
import "jsr:@supabase/functions-js/edge-runtime.d.ts"

const handler = async (_request: Request): Promise<Response> => {
  const res = await fetch("https://api.cricapi.com/v1/currentMatches?apikey=myapikey&offset=0", {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'authorization, x-client-info, apikey, content-type'
    }
  })
  const data = await res.json()
  return new Response(JSON.stringify(data), {
    status: 200,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  })
}

Deno.serve(handler)

When I try to run the same URL with postman it is giving response, but the same one with the above code is giving the error
Note - The above URL does not have any additional authorizations except for apikey used in URL
Am I missing something here??
I have tried to use some dummy URLs available online, and they work perfectly, I have added the CORS headers as well
